# uwsgi timeout after a few POST request

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm trying to host a python program. It works with hosting it via flask, but when I change the setup to flask + uwsgi + nginx, something strange happens: The request (POST) was returned with the proper result. However after a few requests, it will just timeout. After that, even if I restart all the service, the request will also timeout.

I have a UI for test using Ajax and jquery. Each keystroke will call my API searching inside elasticsearch. The timeout starts after a few attempts, the number of attempts is depending on how fast I type.

Everything is running inside docker, glued by docker-compose.

I tried multiple things:

- set the uwsgi timeout in nginx configuration file to a larger value
- set all the timeout parameters in nginx to a larger value
- changed POST method to GET
- added harakiri=30 in uwsgi.ini
- added socket-timeout=60 in uwsgi.ini
- host with uwsgi only by `uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:86 --wsgi-file main.py --callable application --post-buffering 1`

None of them worked, it always timeout at the second request. If the request returns an empty body, it wouldn't timeout.

Something interesting is that when the socket-timeout is set to 60s, it actually starts timeout from the third request sometimes.

Below are my setups:

**Nginx**

> ```
> server {listen <myport>;
> server_name <myip>;
> root /usr/share/nginx/html;
> location / {
>     uwsgi_read_timeout 60s;
>     include uwsgi_params;
>     uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
> } }
> ```

**uwsgi**

> ```
> [uwsgi] 
> socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock 
> chown-socket = www-data:www-data
> chmod-socket = 664 
> uid = www-data 
> gid = www-data 
> cheaper = 0 
> processes = 1
> socket-timeout = 60 
> single-interpreter = true
> wsgi-file = main.py 
> callable = application
> ```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
from <myfile> import _myapiworker
application = Flask(__name__)
@application.route('/_myapi', methods=['POST'])
def myapi():
    req_data = request.get_json()
    <assembling post body>
    res_str = _myapiworker(<post body>)
    return jsonify(res_str)
@application.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=80)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the http to http-socket, like this:

> uwsgi --http-socket 0.0.0.0:86 --wsgi-file main.py --callable
> application --post-buffering 1

Please refer the uwsgi-docs https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html
Note: Do not use --http when you have a frontend webserver or you are doing some form of benchmark, use --http-socket. Continue reading the quickstart to understand why.